# What does mod_pagespeed exactly do?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, mod-pagespeed

I happen to see in my apache log files that my server is getting hit by a specific IP address.

and all the pages that are requested from this IP address has an entry in the apache file 
as

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [04/Dec/2013:10:05:44 -0800] "GET /templates/gk_pXXXX/images/light/column_bg.png HTTP/1.1" 304 111 "-" "Serf/1.1.0 mod_pagespeed/1.4.26.5-3533"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [04/Dec/2013:10:05:44 -0800] "GET /templates/gk_XXXXXX/images/light/top_bg.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 110 "-" "Serf/1.1.0 mod_pagespeed/1.4.26.5-3533"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [04/Dec/2013:10:05:44 -0800] "GET /templates/gk_XXXXX/images/icons3/gkTelephone.png HTTP/1.1" 304 109 "-" "Serf/1.1.0 mod_pagespeed/1.4.26.5-3533"
```

and it has now more than 30k hits within 15mins. Due to this my site is taking is forever to load. What is the reason? Can we make it harmful?

Comment: `Serf` appears to be a client library for HTTP, and mod_pagespeed is actually a server-side optimization library. You're either being hit with a DoS or someone's load testing your site...which is unlikely since it's been a long period.

Comment: Either of that reason would bother me because no one doing any of these from my side as far as I know. I am afraid that is is from an unwelcome person! how do I differentiate if it is a bot or human or script that is hitting my server?

Comment: First of all - see if you can identify the IP address and who it's allocated to. If it belongs to google, make sure that you don't have a Webmaster who signed up for Page Optimization as a service

Comment: I made sure about that. It does not belong to google. I know the IP address (I would reveal it if that will help this question). It belongs to my hosting service. So I want to make sure if is an intrusion or something harmless before I come to a decision.

Comment: What, specifically, would you like us to tell you? Do you want to know what `mod_pagespeed` does? Do you want to know what this IP address is? Do you want to know how to blocks requests from a specific IP? Your question is kind of all over the place - take a few minutes to collect your thoughts and present a more coherent, well-reasoned question...

Comment: I know what the IP address is. I know how to block requests from a specific IP and as far as I know `mod-pagespeed` is to optimize and make the website faster. But in my case it is the other way round. It is making the website terribly slow. I still cannot find the exact reason behind this.

Comment: @Venky Please take 15 minutes and *clarify your question*, *you* will also need to do some investigation and troubleshooting on *your end* before anyone can help you ([mod_pagespeed can do a ***LOT*** of things](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/config_filters), many can make your site slower if your server isn't up for the extra work - we can't help you if we don't know more about your configuration.

Comment: Ok. IP address of my website is `208.113.214.125`. I am getting hit by my own server because of this mod_pagespeed.

Comment: All I want to know is if someone deliberately created the problem or anyother reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find out who installed mod_pagespeed on your server and talk to them.

Comment: How do I find that? Right now there is only one user active in my server. So finding the person using user activities is not an option.

Comment: Mod_pagespeed is something an administrator on your server must have installed and configured, the same way all the other software on your server was installed and configured. Talk to the people who administer your server.

Comment: So it can even be harmful to my own website?